# Golang grpc: how scalable is it?

Tags: go, grpc

How scalable is GRPC on Go?

Can I run a GRPC server for every IoT device connected to my server app? I.e. have 10-20k of GRPC servers per process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean a new grpc listening TCP port for each service?  Go can't fix the scalability of that; huge numbers of TCP listeners has scalability issues at the scope of the operating system.

If you instead mean a TCP listener doing a reverse proxy back to thousands of other devices, then Go is a pretty good fit for that.  What Go does well is cheap "threads", because they don't have to allocate full thread stacks.  In Go, spawning a "goroutine" costs about 4k, rather than being a 1MB minimum penalty vs a real thread.

grpc is designed to tranpsport over http2 and reuse the socket efficiently, and pack data efficiently.

Comment: "do you mean a new grpc listening TCP port for each service" Yes, I meant having a listener for each device. "a TCP listener doing a reverse proxy back to thousands of other devices" that was my backup plan, but it requires a bit more bookkeeping and synchronization.

Comment: in any case, i haven't seen anything about grpc or Go that indicate bad scalability.  it is really easy to write scalable code in Go, because the libraries don't make big mistakes like slurping io streams into huge byte arrays, or writing unnecessarily blocking code.  grpc in particular is just an efficient binary encoding for use inside an http2 transport.

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming. I guess you are right, having one listener and doing a revers proxy makes more sense.